# Data structure for choosing random elements?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures, random

Does anyone know of a data structure that supports the two operations efficiently?

1. Insert a value into the data structure.
2. Dequeue and return an entry from the data structure with uniformly random probability.

This is sort of like the canonical "bag of marbles" that always comes up in introductory probability classes.  You can put arbitrary marbles into the bag, and can then efficiently remove the marbles at random.

The best solution I have is as follows - use a self-balancing binary search tree (AVL, AA, red/black, etc.) to store the elements.  This gives O(lg n) insertion time.  To remove a random element, pick a random index i, then locate and remove the ith element from the tree.  If you've augmented the structure appropriately, this can be made to run in O(lg n) time as well.

This runtime certainly isn't bad, but I'm curious if it's possible to do better - perhaps O(1) for insertion and O(lg n) for dequeues?  Or perhaps something that runs in *expected* O(1) insert and delete using hash functions?  Or perhaps a stronger amortized bound?

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this asymptotically faster?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: does anybody know whether this data structure has a name? It's obviously a type of `Bag` and/or `MultiSet`. `RandomBag`, maybe? In fact, what are such data structures (i.e. data structures where `pop` returns and removes a random element) called *in general*?

Comment: I've heard the terms Bag and RandomBag used here, but I think RandomBag is probably the proper term; Bag is usually a synonym for multiset.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes. Use a vector.

To insert, simply place at the end, and increment the size. To remove, pick an element at random, swap its contents with the end value, then pop off the end value (i.e., return the end value and decrement the vector's size).

Both operations are amortised O(1).

Comment: When you don't need to keep order, data structures are so simple :)

Comment: Beautiful!  That's a fantastic solution.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @templatetypedef: My pleasure. :-) BTW, if you're applying to Google, you're expected to know that this method is basically a variant of Fisher-Yates shuffle. Except that instead of leaving the shuffled values in the array, you're extracting them all out. :-P